# Simple Autocomplete in WPF Code Behind with an event which fires after selection is done

Tags: c#, wpf, autocomplete

I wanted to implement Autocomplete in WPF C# (without using MVVM model) . I got an example but it was a MVVM model example . I am new to WPF so wanted to simply incorporate an Autocomplete feature with an event which will fire after the selection is done in AutoComplete Textbox . 
FYI : I am using Metro Mahapps theme to do my project .

Thanks in advance .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no standard WPF control available in order to achieve this functionality.
However, there are third party controls available.
[teleric RadAutocompleteBox](http://docs.telerik.com/devtools/wpf/controls/radautocompletebox/overview)

If you don't want third party controls, you could do it manually as explained: [here](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/dpatra/autocomplete-textbox-in-wpf/)